# Is it possible to keep same-named global variables unique across different scripts after importing them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, python-import

So I have a few Python scripts that I want to run simultaneously, so I made a new empty Python script that just `import`s all of my scripts so that I can run all of them with a single script. However, most of the scripts have global variable names in them that are the same name across some of the scripts, but I don't want them conflicting with each other. Is there a way without going into the scripts individually one by one to change the names of every single global variable that I can still "load" all the scripts into a single file and share the same global variable names without them conflicting with each other?

Comment: generally speaking no.  global variables are available everywhere in the main thread unless the same value is assigned within a function.  I would recommend using class objects or changing your functions to return a value. If possible, edit your answer and post some example code.  I may be misunderstanding your question.

Comment: This problem won't happen if you import each script properly with the `import myscript` syntax. So I suspect that you're doing `from myscript import *`, which is a recipe for name collisions.

Comment: rewrite yours scripts, not to use global variables. That's the best way to avoid problems with global variables.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to do that!

Every module has a seperate global scope. As an example, you can see this by doing this:

#### test.py

```
a = 1

def set_a(val):
    global a
    a = val

def get_a():
    return a
```

#### test_two.py

```
import test

a = 4
test.set_a(5)
print(a)  # 4
print(test.a)  # 5
```

As long as you don't import them into the same namespace. If you do, if you assign it anywhere with `name = value`, the name `a` in `test` would be different to the name in `test_two`:

#### test_two.py

```
from test import a, set_a, get_a

print((get_a(), a))  # (1, 1)
set_a(5)
print((get_a(), a))  # (5, 1)
a = 4
print((get_a(), a))  # (5, 4)
```

But this won't happen if you mutate the value, for example, `.append`ing to a list, the names will still point to the same values.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `util.py` file and define all your global variables in there. Now, you just need to make changes in only one file if you wish to updated a variable name.

Here's some code:

```
# util.py

def init():
    global myVar
    myVar = []
```

In another file:

```
# file.py

import util
```